# The .replace function is not working and does not replace part of my string

Tags: python

I am working on a code for my robotics team that gets ranks of teams from a website and puts them on a spreadsheet. To get the team, I get a string that outputs "frc""teamnumber". So I want to get rid of the "frc" and just get teamnumber. So I tried using .replace('frc', ''). That didnt work and still printed a "frc""teamnumber". I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. Thanks!

```
`workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('SCOUTRANKS.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

z = '2018ctsct'

def cutit(s,n):
   return s[n:]

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': 1,
    'border': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': 'yellow'})

worksheet.write(col, 0, 'Ranks', bold)

teamNumber = 'team_key'
c = teamNumber.replace('frc','')

teamRanks = tba.event_rankings(z).get('rankings')
teamrankDict = {}
for rank in teamRanks:
    b = rank.get(c)
    teamrankDict[rank.get("rank")] = b
row = 1

print(teamrankDict)
```

`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  There is way too much code for this question.  Please pare it done to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Provide a self-contained [MCVE] without the irrelevant file I/O.

Comment: You made an assignment: `teamNumber = 'team_key'`, before you use `replace`. `teamNumber` has no `frc` substring in it and thus `replace` will not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string always starts with "frc", then it'd be computationally and logically easier if you just indexed to remove the string.

For example, if you have a string `str = "frc2019"`, then `str[3:]` will return `"2019"`. The [3:] is saying *give me the substring of str that starts at index 3 and goes to the end of the word.*